# Getting error using AVERAGEIFS in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am trying to get the average score that team members in Team 3 in a given quarter gave for a question.

Column D contains team names, Column E contains the scores (on a 0-10 range). Column AK contains the quarter the team answered in (e.g. FY22 Q4). Here is my query:

=​AVERAGEIFS($D$2:$D$2402, E$2:E$2402, "Team 3", '$AK$2:$AK$2402, "FY22 Q4")

The error I get is: "Evaluation of function AVERAGEIFS caused a divide by zero error."

Please can you help?

Comment: Keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet. Asking the volunteers here to "imagine it" will be a deterrent, as the time any of us can donate is limited. Help us help you by sharing a link to a sample spreadsheet *showing* us what you're trying to tell us currently.

Comment: did you notice that there is a stray apostrophe in your formula? --> '$AK$2:$AK$2402

Answer (score 0):

The correct query to use is:

```
=AVERAGEIFS( E2:E2402, D2:D2402,"Team 3", AK2:AK2402 ,"FY22 Q4")
```

that is (order of elements):

```
scores teamNames teamType quarters quarterType
```

...maybe even adding an error check with

```
=iferror( AVERAGEIFS ( E2:E2402, D2:D2402,"Team 3", AK2:AK2402 ,"FY22 Q4"),"")
```

Comment: Thanks. Just sharing a sheet with sample data and sample results: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A2-7tk8STODnccUWwI0tCFyEgWxUxSsqtDfc7MCjq0o/edit?usp=sharing

Is there a better approach than what I'm thinking to achieve these results?

Comment: @user1916846
 just now adapted the calculation to your sample sheet

Comment: Perfect thank you very much